# Divide row values in a pandas DataFrame by a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
                1     2     3     4  Density
Mineral                                     
Quartz       13.4  23.0  23.4  28.3    2.648
Plagioclase   5.2   8.2   8.5  11.7    2.620
K-feldspar    2.3   2.4   2.6   3.1    2.750
```

What I need to do is to calculate the new rows based on the condition made on the row:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
                 1     2     3     4     Density 
Mineral                                                           
Quartz         13.4  23.0  23.4  28.3    2.648
Plagioclase     5.2   8.2   8.5  11.7    2.620
K-feldspar      2.3   2.4   2.6   3.1    2.750
Quartz_v       5.06  8.69  8.84 10.69    2.648
Plagioclase_v   ...
```

So the process is basically I need to the following steps:

1) Define the new row, for example, **Quartz_v**

2) and then perform the following calculation **Quartz_v** = each column value of **Quartz** divided by the **Density** value of **Quartz_v**

I have already loaded the data as a two dataframes, the density and mineral ones, and merged them, so the each mineral will have the correct density in front of it.

Comment: can you share your desired output

Comment: Desire output is actually the second table

Comment: I've fixed your input and output so that your question and my answer are consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

- `DataFrame.div` with axis=0 to perform division,
- `rename` to rename the index, and
- `append` to concatenate the result to the original (you can also use `pd.concat` instead).

```
d = df['Density']
result = df.append(df.div(d, axis=0).assign(Density=d).rename(lambda x: x+'_v'))
result

                       1          2          3          4  Density
Mineral                                                           
Quartz         13.400000  23.000000  23.400000  28.300000    2.648
Plagioclase     5.200000   8.200000   8.500000  11.700000    2.620
K-feldspar      2.300000   2.400000   2.600000   3.100000    2.750
Quartz_v        5.060423   8.685801   8.836858  10.687311    2.648
Plagioclase_v   1.984733   3.129771   3.244275   4.465649    2.620
K-feldspar_v    0.836364   0.872727   0.945455   1.127273    2.750
```